Confusion between displacement and distance in pendulum
I was reading this page on the motion on the pendulum. It defines $s$ to be the displacement of the pendulum along the arc. Later, it says that $s=l\theta$ by the arc length formula. How is this? The arc length formula is supposed to be for the length of the curved arc, but $s$ is the displacement, by which I understand a sort of straight line between the starting point and the point at which the bob is now.
What am I missing here?

Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Sometimes people are surprised by this, but there are terms that mean one thing in a certain setting, and a slightly different thing in some other setting (perhaps when associated with a modifier, but often even without one). It's not a major problem, but it does happen. You then have to infer the exact meaning from context, and/or by taking note of the precise wording used, or if available, look up the definition given in that particular work. This is true of physics, and every other discipline out there - including mathematics (even though things there are defined as precisely as can be).

The key words are displacement along the arc. If you are restricted to moving along the circle, then the "shortest path" you're thinking of is the arc. The form of Newton's second law makes it clear what they mean, because they only consider the force component tangential to the arc.
Just to be clear, this isn't some one-off definition of displacement. If you were asked to measure the displacement between your home and a neighboring town/city, you would probably measure it along the surface of the earth, and not as a "straight line" through the bit of earth crust between your house and the town/city.


move the pendulum with small $~d\theta~$
you obtain
$$\tan(d\theta)\approx d\theta=\frac {ds}{L}\quad\Rightarrow\\
L\,\int d\theta=\int ds\quad,L\,\theta=s $$
